# "Taylor series" of a knot crossing - does that make sense?

Tags: knot-theory

Assume you have a knot "colored" with the irrep of a quantum Lie algebra with its parameter at $q=1+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is small. When it is zero, all crossings turn virtual. Does it make any sense to do a Taylor series of a crossing (in form of a skein relation), writing something like $overcross=virtual+\epsilon*quartic casimir+...,undercross=virtual-\epsilon*...$ (quarticcasimir stands for "I have no idea :-)

I experimented a bit; at least $(overcross-undercross)/\epsilon$ seems to be "compatible" with the formalism. E.g. take the R matrix $R$ of the defining irrep $7$ of $G_2$. Its eigenvalues are $1/q^2(27),-q^6(7),q^{12}(1),-1(14)$, where the multiplicities are in brackets (and are the dimensions in $7\bigotimes 7=27\bigoplus 7\bigoplus 1\bigoplus 14$; the exponents of $q$ are the quadratic casimirs). Then $A=lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} (R-R^{-1})/\epsilon$  has eigenvalues $-4(27),-12(7),24(1),0(14)$, which "looks good" (read: the multiplicities are OK, and you surely noted the eigenvalues are the quadratic casimirs times 2).

Comment: Do you know about Vassiliev/finite-type invariants? One way you can get them is by expanding quantum invariants in power series in $h$, where $q = e^h$. This looks like what you're doing here.

Comment: Yes, I do, but mostly by name, and I also noted a certain similarity, but I wasn't sure if my construction was legit at all. (Point: $R+R^{-1}$ "gives" a virtual crossing, which does not mix well with real crossings, man forbidden move.) But now that you said it, it might be interesting to see if I get to second order in $\epsilon$ with a similar construction.

Comment: I think that the expansion of crossings in "chord diagrams" is something like your power-series expansion of the $R$-matrix. But I haven't studied them in a while, so this analogy may be off.

Comment: In any case, it seems to work with more than one R matrix: Let $RR$ be the $n^2*n^2$ matrix "Outer(Times,$R$,$R$)" (you need a bit more Mathematica code to orient the upper and lower legs correctly - this shall represent simply two crossings drawn aside to each other, like in the Vassiliev invariant). Let $S=R^{-1}$ and define $SS,RS,SR$ analogous to $RR$. Then $RR+SS-RS-SR$ is an $\epsilon^2$ term at $q=1$ and it seems that the eigenvalues are linear independent of those in $\epsilon$ (namely $RR-SS,RR-SR,RR-RS$). Whatever that means :-)